# jquery on click change only this input value or link data attruibe from a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php loop that call products from database. there is a quantity input field and a ajax add to cart button.
Now ajax add cart function get product id and quantity from the add cart link data attribute. So I want that when I change the quantity field value the add cart link data-quantity will changed automatically. So I can add sent the product quantity to cart.

I tried to do this but unfortunately its change all products quantity on click, because of same class. there is any why to do this that only change the quantity where I clicked?

maybe product id class work here? but how I set a dynamic product id in jquery?

here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img1.jpg" /><br />
        <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <button class="button">+</button>
    <button class="button">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="input" value="1" min="1" />
        <a href="product.php?add-to-cart=1" data-id="1" data-quantity="1" class="add-to-cart ajax product-1">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img2.jpg" /><br />
        <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <button class="button">+</button>
    <button class="button">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="input" value="1" min="1" />
        <a href="product.php?add-to-cart=2" data-id="2" data-quantity="1" class="add-to-cart ajax product-2">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img3.jpg" /><br />
        <h2>Product 3</h2>
    <button class="button">+</button>
    <button class="button">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="input" value="1" min="1" />
        <a href="product.php?add-to-cart=3" data-id="3" data-quantity="1" class="add-to-cart ajax product-2">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img4.jpg" /><br />
        <h2>Product 4</h2>
    <button class="button">+</button>
    <button class="button">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="input" value="1" min="1" />
        <a href="product.php?add-to-cart=4" data-id="4" data-quantity="1" class="add-to-cart ajax product-4">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $(".button").on("click", function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   var oldValue = $('.input').val();

   if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
       // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 1) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
        newVal = 1;
      }
      }
    $('a.add-to-cart').attr('data-quantity', newVal);
    $('.input').val(newVal);
 });
});
</script>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/alshedupur/pen/KmMxJv

**Please don't push minus before give me a solution. Maybe you know this, but I don't know. If you share your knowledge it will help me and maybe others too.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use selector that matches all inputs as they share the class, you can either push an unique id per item or you can use selector to find only items within the same container.

E.g.

```
$(function() {
 $(".button").on("click", function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   var $parent = $button.parent(); 
   var oldValue = $parent.find('.input').val();

   if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
       // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 1) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
        newVal = 1;
      }
      }
    $parent.find('a.add-to-cart').attr('data-quantity', newVal);
    $parent.find('.input').val(newVal);
 });
});
```

Comment: I change this, its work for 1st product but others are start from 1st product quantity. example: if 1st product quantity is 14 after then if you click the 2nd or 3rd product this product quantity starts from 15 and stack, if press +, if press - then it will be 13 then stack! here is the url: https://codepen.io/alshedupur/pen/KmMxJv

Comment: You also need to take the oldValue from the parent container input, didn't change that in my example. Updated my example.